# How to get total amount of retweets for multiple Twitter tweets in least amount of queries?

Tags: php, rest, twitter, analytics

**Background:** I work with a system that posts tweets from the same account, but for different people, and then gets the analytics for those tweets. One of the analytics is a retweets count.

**Current Implementation:**
I get all the tweet IDs for a certain user and send a request for each ID. With the Rest API I have 200 or 350 requests per hour. When user has too many tweets posted (and with this system number of tweets can reach 100-200 very fast), the requests get blocked due to the limits of the Rest API - I have 200 or 350 requests per hour. So if user hits too many tweets, he won't be able to get his analytics and will block that availability for others as well.

**Question**: Is there a way to send a request to Twitter with a list of Tweets IDs and receive a list of retweeters information for each of the IDs?

**UPD: basically I need something like GET statuses / user_timeline, but for certain IDs...**

**UPD2: there is also GET statuses / lookup, but it doesn't return retweeters.**

Comment: Is this for good or evil?

Comment: @mdewitt for good. It's a system for automatical "socializing" of blogs. People register there and new posts from their blogs are tweeted (it's not the only thing, but only this matters here). And they're tweeted through a single account, with mentioning author's name and listing his followers on our site. Number of followers can be big, that's why it's separated into many tweets. I need to get retweets for all those tweets of an author.

Comment: Due to that I need also a tweet reach, i.e. total number of retweeters' followers + my followers, I found 2 differently bad ways. One: get number of retweets in one request, then reach in many other requests for each tweet. Second: get number of retweets and reach in one request for every tweet. Obviously, second is better, but it still can reach too large number of request at once.